# how to set currentpage to be last with dir-paginate

Tags: angularjs

I am using : https://github.com/michaelbromley/angularUtils/tree/master/src/directives/pagination

I want after adding a new element to the list, to make my currentPage be the last page.
I tried using the paginationService like this:

```
paginationService.setCurrentPage('ID', Math.ceil(paginationService.getCollectionLength("ID")/ITEMSPERPAGE));
```

However, the problem is that the collection is updated after a few miliseconds, which means that the 'getCollectionLength' function will not return the correctValue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I decided to try and use the $timeout module from angular, since it made sense dir-paginate would use the same clicks angular uses to update.
It works just as expected, code is now:

```
$timeout(function() { 
        paginationService.setCurrentPage('ID', Math.ceil(paginationService.getCollectionLength("ID")/ITEMSPERPAGE));
    });
```

Just make sure you have $timeout in the modules import AND in the function params for the ng-controller. Silly mistake, but I forgot to do it.