# dir-pagination in angularJS: move to page X of the paginated table

Tags: angularjs, dirpagination

I used dir-paginate for the first time in angularJS and it was very easy to have a pagination that works as desired... Until I noticed a small problem.
The items are now correctly paginated, when I go in the details of an Item (a row) I have a button "back" that should bring me on the page where the item was.

For example, if I am on page 4 and click on any item, I go to a page with its details, then I want to create a button "back" that should bring the user to page 4.

The code of my table is quite easy, I just used dir-paginate on the item list and added  at the end of the page.
On the button I wanted to create, I tried to use setCurrent(4) - for now using a fix number, but nothing happens. I suppose because detail page is in a totally different page and the pagination is not visible from there.

I just had to change my table into something like this:

```
<table class="mytable">
<thead>
<tr> headers th..</tr>
</thead>

<tbody>
<tr dir-paginate="record in filteredData = (data | itemsPerPage: 20)"> columns... </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<dir-pagination-controls></dir-pagination-controls>
```

how could I go directly to page X of such table?

Answer (score 0):

I found that the new button works if in the controller, the function paginationService.setCurrentPage is called in $timeout, as following:

```
$timeout(function() { 
        paginationService.setCurrentPage('__default', thePage));
    });
```

Of course after importing $timeout object.

So I created a wrapper as following:

```
        vm.setCurrentPagination = function(numeroPagina){
            $timeout(function () {
                paginationService.setCurrentPage('__default', numeroPagina);
            });
        };
```

I found here the trick:
[how to set currentpage to be last with dir-paginate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41754355/how-to-set-currentpage-to-be-last-with-dir-paginate)